# Matrix Transpose Property Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a square matrix such that $A^T*A=A$
Prove that $A^2 = A$ and also show that $A$ is symmetrical.

I'm not sure how to go about this problem. I can only think of using an identity matrix but I'm not sure if that will work.

Anything helps thanks !

Comment: It says that A is a square matrix, which means that rows = columns, i.e. if we take m as rows and n as columns then m = n for A. Use this concept to show that A is symmetrical and use A^T*A = A to get to A^2 = A.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.* $A^TA=A\Rightarrow(A^TA)^T=A^T$.

Answer (score 0):

If $A^tA = A$, then 
$$A = A^tA = (A^tA)^t = A^t$$
which means that $A$ is symmetric. Now, return to your original equation to conclude that $AA = A$, that is, $A^2 = A$.